# Docker compose not doing anything

Tags: docker, docker-compose

If I run this command: `docker-compose up --detach`:

It just returns the default information about Docker:

```
Builds, (re)creates, starts, and attaches to containers for a service.

Unless they are already running, this command also starts any linked services.

The `docker-compose up` command aggregates the output of each container. When
the command exits, all containers are stopped. Running `docker-compose up -d`
starts the containers in the background and leaves them running.

If there are existing containers for a service, and the service's configuration
or image was changed after the container's creation, `docker-compose up` picks
up the changes by stopping and recreating the containers (preserving mounted
volumes). To prevent Compose from picking up changes, use the `--no-recreate`
flag.
```

How can I get it to run?

I've tried `docker-compose up -d`, which returns:

`ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon - you might need to run` docker-machine start default`.

Comment: Are you sure you are in the same directory where are your `docker-ompose.yml` exists?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the Docker daemon is running? Try running this:

```
sudo systemctl start docker
```

Or on older systems:

```
sudo service docker start
```

You can also use environment variables to debug what is the problem with the Docker daemon:

```
eval "$(docker-machine env default)"
```

then

```
docker-compose --verbose up -d
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems `Docker` daemon is not running. Start it by this command (temporarily until the next reboot):

```
systemctl start docker
```

If on older OSes:

```
service docker start
```

Then run your command `docker-compose up -d`. If it worked, now you should `enable` docker so that when you reboot the OS, the daemon starts automatically:

```
systemctl enable docker
```

If on older OSes:

```
service docker enable
```